# check url and redirect if inactive

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have been working on a script that will redirect the page to a url if the user has been inactif for a a while ( for the test I put 5 secs). 
I am missing something as the script redirects even when the user is active... could you help me out point what is wrong in my code? 
The function will check if an iframe url contains a certain string, if so  it will trigger the redirecturl function.

```
var timeoutID;

function setup() {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
}
setup();

function startTimer() {
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 5000);
}

function resetTimer(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    goActive();
}

function redirecturl() {
     window.location.replace("http://google.com");
}

function goInactive() {
  // Check if the iframe url contains KDMPK 
  var srcurl = document.getElementById("nookalbooking").src;
  var n = srcurl.includes("KDMPK");

    if(n==true) {
      redirecturl();
    }
     //else
     //{
     // goActive();
     //           
     //}
}

function goActive() { 
    startTimer();
}
```

Comment: have you thought perhaps adding some console logging to see what is being called when?

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot. I have updated the script. See below

Answer (score 0):

You should add your event listeners to the `document`:

```
function setup() {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks heaps guys, it turns out that I am ran into a cross domain security that I didn't think off since my target is an iframe. 
I have updated the script and got over the cross domain security issue somehow I think, here is the new version. 
The timer starts ticking once an activity is recorded on the iframe, then after 7 minutes the page will refresh and go back to the homepage - even if the user is still active which is annoying. I cannot get the reset timer to work though, any idea?

```
<div class="iframe">
<iframe id="nookalbooking" src="https://bookings.nookal.com/bookings" width="100%" height="1950" allowtransparency="true" style=" border:0px solid #CCCCCC; border-radius: 3px;"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    var timeoutID;
    var myConfObj = {
  iframeMouseOver : false
};

function startTimer() {
    // wait 2 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 70000);
}
function goInactive() {
    location.reload();

}
function goActive() {
    // do something 
    startTimer();
}
function resetTimer(e) {
   window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
   goActive();
}

window.addEventListener('blur',function(){
  if(myConfObj.iframeMouseOver){
  resetTimer();
  }
  else {
    goInactive();

  }
});

document.getElementById('nookalbooking').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = true;

});

document.getElementById('nookalbooking').addEventListener('touchmove',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = true; 
});

document.getElementById('nookalbooking').addEventListener('MSPointerMove',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = true; 
});

document.getElementById('nookalbooking').addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
    myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = false;

});

</script>
```